# Definite Integral in two variables equal zero

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Under what condition the following statement is true?

$$ \int_{0}^{1} p(i,t)di =\lambda(t) \int_{0}^{1} y(i,t)di \Rightarrow p(i,t) = \lambda(t) y(i,t) \forall i\in[0,1] $$

My guess was that I need to assume that:

$$ \int_{0}^{x} p(i,t)di =\lambda(t) \int_{0}^{x} y(i,t)di \quad \forall x\in[0,1] $$
and of course that they are continuos in the interval. Is it enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is enough.
If we take your assumption and differentiate with respect to $x$, we get
$$
p(x,t)=\lambda(t)y(x,t).
$$
Therefore if you fix any $t$ and assume your assumption for all $i\in[0,1]$, then the conclusion holds for that $t$ and all $i\in[0,1]$.
It also works for all $t$, but it is strong enough to work one value of $t$ at a time.

I assumed that $p$ and $y$ are continuous with respect to the first argument.
What you assumed is equivalent with what you want.
Integrating the claim gives the assumption and differentiation goes the other way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was just wondering if i can assume something less restrictive and still get the same result, but for that i don't have any particular idea.

Comment: @G.p. What you assumed is equivalent with what you want. Integrating the claim gives the assumption and differentiation goes the other way.

Comment: Really useful, thanks a lot.